# What is the maximum possiblity for an integer polynomial to be divisible by a prime number?

Tags: probability, number-theory, probability-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

#### Description

Given a prime number $p$, a natural number $n < p$, and a **random variable** x from a [discrete uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution) $\mathcal{u} = \text{unif}\{1,p-1\}$.
Let polynomial

$$Q(x) = a_{p-2}x^{p-2} + a_{p-3}x^{p-3} + \dots a_{1}x + a_0,$$

and $P(A|B)$ is the [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) of A given B. What is
$$\gamma_{p,n} = \max_{a_i \in \mathbb{Z} \forall i = 0,1,\dots p-2\ \land\ 0 < \sum |a_i| \le n} P(Q(x)\ mod\ p = 0 | x \sim u)?$$

If computing the exact value of $\gamma_{p,n}$ is hard, I'm also interested in the possible upper bound of it.  Is there such a constant $C$ such that $\gamma_{p,n} \le \frac{C}{p}$ for sufficiently large $p$ and $n \le \frac{p}{C}$? If not are there any similar conclusions?

If there is no conclusion for general $p$, are there any conclusions for a specific $p$? E.g., If $p = 2^{31}-1$what could be the range of $C$ such that $\gamma_{p, \lceil\frac{p}{C}\rceil} \le \frac{C}{p}$? When $C = 10$, what are the set of $p$ such that $\gamma_{p, \lceil\frac{p}{C}\rceil} < \frac{C}{p}$?

What if the random variable $x$ is uniformly drawn from a subset $S$ of natural numbers that is smaller than $p$ (i.e., $S = \{e| e \in \mathbb{N^+} \land e < p\}$)? Let
$$\gamma^S_{p,n} = \max_{a_i \in \mathbb{Z} \forall i = 0,1,\dots p-2\ \land\ 0 < \sum |a_i| \le n} P(Q(x)\ mod\ p = 0 | x \sim S)?$$. What kind of $S$ can give us a good bound on $\gamma^S_{p,n}$ (i.e., $\exists C, \ \gamma^S_{p, \lceil\frac{p}{C}\rceil} < \frac{C}{p}$ )?

#### Example

Let $p = 3$, $n = 1$, then $x$ is randomly drawn from $\mathcal{u}=$unif{1,2} (i.e., $P(x=1|x \sim \mathcal{u})$ $=$ $P(x=2|x \sim \mathcal{u})$ $=$ $0.5$).

When $a_1 = 0, a_0 = 1,Q(x) = 1$  so $P(Q(x)\ mod\ p = 0 | x \sim u) = 0$.

When $a_1 = 0, a_0 = -1,Q(x) = -1$  so $P(Q(x)\ mod\ p = 0 | x \sim u) = 0$.

When $a_1 = 1, a_0 = 0,Q(x) = x$  so $P(Q(x)\ mod\ p = 0 | x \sim u) = 0$.

When $a_1 = -1, a_0 = 0,Q(x) = -x$  so $P(Q(x)\ mod\ p = 0 | x \sim u) = 0$.

Above are all possible combinations of $a_0,a_1$ such that $a_0,a_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $0 < \sum |a_i| \le n = 1$. Thus
$$\gamma_{3,1} = \max_{a_0,a_1 \in \mathbb{Z} \land\ 0 < |a_0| + |a_1| \le 1} P(Q(x)\ mod\ 3 = 0 | x \sim u) = 0.$$

Comment: What is the definition of capital $P$? Can you give an example for a small $p$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks for the comment! I have updated the question.